# Bundle declarations into one statement or not?

Tags: objective-c, coding-style

Given the following Objective-C example, is it simply a matter of style and ease of reading to keep separate statements or to bundle them into one?  Are there any actual benefits of either? Is it a waste of memory to declare individual variables?

```
NSDictionary *theDict = [anObject methodToCreateDictionary];
NSArray *theValues = [theDict allValues];
NSString *theResult = [theArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

or

```
NSString *theResult = [[[anObject methodToCreateDictionary] theValues] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 2):

I take the following into consideration when I declare a separate variable:

- If I might want to see its value in the debugger.
- If I am accessing the variable more than once.
- If the line is too long.

There is no practical difference between the two approaches, however.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you haven't asked directly about this, but be aware, when you access objects using dot notation, for example:

```
myObject.myObjectProperty1.myObjectProperty1Property;
```

If you are going to access `myObjectProperty1Property` more than once, it can be advisable to assign it to a local named variable. If you don't, the look-up will be executed more than once.

Now I can't emphasise enough, for many if not most situations this time saving is so infinitesimal as to seriously call into question whether it is worth even spending the time doing extra typing for the assignation! So why am I raising this? Because having said that -  stylistic "anality" apart (I just made up a new word) - if the section of code you are writing is running in a tight loop, it can be worth taking the extra care. An example would be when writing the code which populates the cells in a UICollectionView that contains a large number of cells. Additionally, if you are using Core Data and you are using the dot notation to refer to the properties of NSManagedObject properties, then there is far greater overhead with each and every look-up, in which case it is much more surely worth taking the time to assign any values referred to by "nested" dot notation calls to a local variable first.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution.  I get your point, but I wonder, wouldn't it be the same thing taking the time to assign a value to a local variable with or without dot notation, given such a scenario?

Comment: No because in objective C ivar's are accessed via object messaging. You can define any iVar access methods to include any functionality you like and the complier doesn't know in advance if you need your method  to be run, so in objective c, dot notation corresponds to nested method calls with the ivar access method fired for each dot. For any given code, fewer dots equals less messages fired. Some have speculated that for certain code patterns, theoretically, this could be optimised by the compiler. In practice it seems, for whatever reason, it is not.